# ¿Cómo traducir los modelos de activeadmin en los mensaje de error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy usando Activeadmin, tengo un problema a la hora de traducir los nombres de los modelos que aparecen en los errores.

Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Implemente la gema [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale/) para poder traducir los mensajes de los errores que proceden de un recurso con un relación `has_many :customers, :dependent => :restrict_with_error`, si la quito de mi Gemfile y paso bundle nuevamente, los mensajes se ven así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en **app/config/initializers/activeadmin.rb**, agregue el siguiente código para mostrar los errores, ya que antes no aparecían:

```
private

  def interpolation_options
    options = {}
    options[:resource_errors] =
    if resource && resource.errors.any?
      "#{resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}."
    else
      ""
    end

    options
  end
```

Esta es mi configuración en **app/config/application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Software
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.locale = :es
    config.i18n.default_locale = :es

    #config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false

    config.time_zone = 'America/Santiago'
end
end
```

Mi archivo **config/locales/es.yml**

```
es: 
  active_admin: 
    access_denied: 
      message: "No está autorizado/a a realizar esta acción."
    any: Cualquiera
    batch_actions: 
      action_label: "%{title} seleccionados"
      button_label: "Acciones en masa"
      default_confirmation: "¿Seguro que quieres hacer esto?"
      delete_confirmation: "Eliminar %{plural_model}: ¿Está seguro?"
      labels: 
        destroy: Borrar
      selection_toggle_explanation: "(Cambiar selección)"
      succesfully_destroyed: 
        one: "Se ha destruido 1 %{model} con éxito"
        other: "Se han destruido %{count} %{plural_model} con éxito"
    blank_slate: 
      content: "No hay %{resource_name} aún."
      link: Añadir
    cancel: Cancelar
    comments: 
      add: Comentar
      author: Autor
      author_missing: Anónimo
      author_type: "Tipo de autor"
      body: Cuerpo
      created_at: "Fecha de creación"
      delete: "Borrar Comentario"
      delete_confirmation: "¿Está seguro que desea borrar este comentario?"
      errors: 
        empty_text: "El comentario no fue guardado, el texto estaba vacío."
      no_comments_yet: "No hay comentarios aún."
      resource: Recurso
      resource_type: "Tipo de recurso"
      title_content: "Comentarios (%{count})"
    create_another: "Crear otro %{model}"
    dashboard: Inicio
    dashboard_welcome: 
      call_to_action: "Para agregar secciones edite 'app/admin/dashboard.rb'"
      welcome: "Bienvenido a Active Admin. Esta es la página de inicio predeterminada."
    delete: Eliminar
    delete_confirmation: "¿Está seguro de que quiere eliminar esto?"
    delete_model: "Eliminar %{model}"
    details: "Detalles de %{model}"
    devise: 
      change_password: 
        submit: "Cambiar mi contraseña"
        title: "Cambie su contraseña"
      email: 
        title: Email
      links: 
        forgot_your_password: "¿Olvidó su contraseña?"
        resend_confirmation_instructions: "Reenviar instrucciones de confirmación"
        resend_unlock_instructions: "Reenviar instrucciones de desbloqueo"
        sign_in: Registrarse
        sign_in_with_omniauth_provider: "Conéctate con %{provider}"
        sign_up: Ingresar
      login: 
        remember_me: Recordarme
        submit: "Iniciar Sesión"
        title: "Iniciar Sesión"
      password: 
        title: Contraseña
      password_confirmation: 
        title: "Confirmar Contraseña"
      resend_confirmation_instructions: 
        submit: "Reenviar instrucciones de confirmación"
        title: "Reenviar instrucciones de confirmación"
      reset_password: 
        submit: "Restablecer mi contraseña"
        title: "¿Olvidó su contraseña?"
      sign_up: 
        submit: Registrarse
        title: Registrarse
      subdomain: 
        title: Subdominio
      unlock: 
        submit: "Reenviar instrucciones de desbloqueo"
        title: "Reenviar instrucciones de desbloqueo"
      username: 
        title: "Nombre de usuario"
    download: "Descargar:"
    dropdown_actions: 
      button_label: Acciones
    edit: Editar
    edit_model: "Editar %{model}"
    empty: Vacío
    errors: 
      messages: 
        record_invalid: "La validación falló: %{errors}"
        restrict_dependent_destroy: 
          has_many: "El registro no puede ser eliminado pues existen %{record} dependientes"
          has_one: "El registro no puede ser eliminado pues existe un %{record} dependiente"
    filters: 
      buttons: 
        clear: "Quitar Filtros"
        filter: Filtrar
      predicates: 
        contains: Contiene
        ends_with: "Termina con"
        equals: "Igual a"
        from: Desde
        greater_than: "Mayor que"
        gteq_datetime: "Mayor o igual que"
        less_than: "Menor que"
        lteq_datetime: "Menor o igual que"
        starts_with: "Empieza con"
        to: Hasta
    has_many_delete: Eliminar
    has_many_new: "Añadir %{model}"
    has_many_remove: Quitar
    index_list: 
      activerecord: ~
      block: Lista
      blog: Blog
      grid: Grilla
      table: Tabla
    logout: Salir
    main_content: "Por favor implemente %{model}#main_content para mostrar contenido."
    move: Mover
    new_model: "Añadir %{model}"
    next: Siguiente
    pagination: 
      empty: "No se han encontrado %{model}"
      entry: 
        one: registro
        other: registros
      multiple: "Mostrando %{model} <b>%{from} - %{to}</b> de un total de <b>%{total}</b>"
      multiple_without_total: "Mostrando %{model} <b>%{from} - %{to}</b>"
      one: "Mostrando <b>1</b> %{model}"
      one_page: "Mostrando <b>un total de %{n}</b> %{model}"
      per_page: "Por página: "
    powered_by: "Funciona con %{active_admin} %{version}"
    previous: Anterior
    search_status: 
      current_filters: "Filtros actuales:"
      current_scope: "Alcance:"
      headline: "Estado de la búsqueda:"
      no_current_filters: Ninguno
    sidebars: 
      filters: Filtros
      search_status: "Estado de la búsqueda"
    status_tag: 
      ? "no"
      : "No"
      ? "yes"
      : Sí
    unsupported_browser: 
      headline: "Por favor tenga en cuenta que Active Admin no soporta versiones de Internet Explorer menores a 8."
      recommendation: "Recomendamos que actualice a la última versión de <a href=\"http://windows.microsoft.com/ie\">Internet Explorer</a>, <a href=\"https://chrome.google.com/\">Google Chrome</a>, o <a href=\"https://mozilla.org/firefox/\">Firefox</a>."
      turn_off_compatibility_view: "Si está usando IE 9 o superior, asegúrese de <a href=\"https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/17471\">apagar la \"Vista de compatibilidad\"</a>."
    view: Ver
  date: 
    abbr_day_names: 
      - dom
      - lun
      - mar
      - mié
      - jue
      - vie
      - sáb
    abbr_month_names: 
      - ~
      - ene
      - feb
      - mar
      - abr
      - may
      - jun
      - jul
      - ago
      - sep
      - oct
      - nov
      - dic
    day_names: 
      - domingo
      - lunes
      - martes
      - miércoles
      - jueves
      - viernes
      - sábado
    formats: 
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
      long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y"
      short: "%d de %b"
    month_names: 
      - ~
      - enero
      - febrero
      - marzo
      - abril
      - mayo
      - junio
      - julio
      - agosto
      - septiembre
      - octubre
      - noviembre
      - diciembre
    order: 
      - !ruby/symbol day
      - !ruby/symbol month
      - !ruby/symbol year
  datetime: 
    distance_in_words: 
      about_x_hours: 
        one: "cerca de 1 hora"
        other: "cerca de %{count} horas"
      about_x_months: 
        one: "cerca de 1 mes"
        other: "cerca de %{count} meses"
      about_x_years: 
        one: "cerca de 1 año"
        other: "cerca de %{count} años"
      almost_x_years: 
        one: "casi 1 año"
        other: "casi %{count} años"
      half_a_minute: "medio minuto"
      less_than_x_minutes: 
        one: "menos de 1 minuto"
        other: "menos de %{count} minutos"
      less_than_x_seconds: 
        one: "menos de 1 segundo"
        other: "menos de %{count} segundos"
      over_x_years: 
        one: "más de 1 año"
        other: "más de %{count} años"
      x_days: 
        one: "1 día"
        other: "%{count} días"
      x_minutes: 
        one: "1 minuto"
        other: "%{count} minutos"
      x_months: 
        one: "1 mes"
        other: "%{count} meses"
      x_seconds: 
        one: "1 segundo"
        other: "%{count} segundos"
      x_years: 
        one: "1 año"
        other: "%{count} años"
    prompts: 
      day: Día
      hour: Hora
      minute: Minuto
      month: Mes
      second: Segundos
      year: Año
  errors: 
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    messages: 
      accepted: "debe ser aceptado"
      blank: "no puede estar en blanco"
      confirmation: "no coincide"
      empty: "no puede estar vacío"
      equal_to: "debe ser igual a %{count}"
      even: "debe ser un número par"
      exclusion: "está reservado"
      greater_than: "debe ser mayor que %{count}"
      greater_than_or_equal_to: "debe ser mayor o igual que %{count}"
      inclusion: "no está incluido en la lista"
      invalid: "es inválido"
      less_than: "debe ser menor que %{count}"
      less_than_or_equal_to: "debe ser menor o igual que %{count}"
      model_invalid: "La validación falló: %{errors}"
      not_a_number: "no es un número"
      not_an_integer: "debe ser un entero"
      odd: "debe ser un número non"
      other_than: "debe ser diferente a %{count}"
      present: "debe estar en blanco"
      required: "debe existir"
      taken: "ya ha sido tomado"
      too_long: 
        one: "es demasiado largo (máximo 1 caracter)"
        other: "es demasiado largo (máximo %{count} caracteres)"
      too_short: 
        one: "es demasiado corto (mínimo 1 caracter)"
        other: "es demasiado corto (mínimo %{count} caracteres)"
      wrong_length: 
        one: "longitud errónea (debe ser de 1 caracter)"
        other: "longitud errónea (debe ser de %{count} caracteres)"
    template: 
      body: "Revise que los siguientes campos sean válidos:"
      header: 
        one: "%{model} no pudo guardarse debido a 1 error"
        other: "%{model} no pudo guardarse debido a %{count} errores"
  flash: 
    actions: 
      destroy: 
        alert: "%{resource_name} No puede ser destruido. %{resource_errors}"
  helpers: 
    page_entries_info: 
      more_pages: 
        display_entries: "Mostrando %{entry_name} <b>%{first} - %{last}</b> de <b>%{total}</b> en total"
      one_page: 
        display_entries: 
          one: "Mostrando <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
          other: "Mostrando <b>todos %{count}</b> %{entry_name}"
          zero: "Ningún %{entry_name} encontrado"
    select: 
      prompt: "Por favor selecciona"
    submit: 
      create: "Crear %{model}"
      submit: "Guardar %{model}"
      update: "Actualizar %{model}"
  number: 
    currency: 
      format: 
        delimiter: ","
        format: "%u%n"
        precision: 2
        separator: "."
        significant: false
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false
        unit: $
    format: 
      delimiter: ","
      precision: 2
      separator: "."
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
    human: 
      decimal_units: 
        format: "%n %u"
        units: 
          billion: "mil millones"
          million: 
            one: millón
            other: millones
          quadrillion: "mil billones"
          thousand: mil
          trillion: 
            one: billón
            other: billones
          unit: ""
      format: 
        delimiter: ","
        precision: 3
        significant: true
        strip_insignificant_zeros: true
      storage_units: 
        format: "%n %u"
        units: 
          byte: 
            one: Byte
            other: Bytes
          gb: GB
          kb: KB
          mb: MB
          tb: TB
    percentage: 
      format: 
        delimiter: ","
        format: "%n%"
    precision: 
      format: 
        delimiter: ","
  support: 
    array: 
      last_word_connector: " y "
      two_words_connector: " y "
      words_connector: ", "
  time: 
    am: am
    formats: 
      default: "%a, %d de %b de %Y a las %H:%M:%S %Z"
      long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y a las %I:%M %p"
      short: "%d de %b a las %H:%M hrs"
    pm: pm
  views: 
    pagination: 
      first: "« Primero"
      last: "Último »"
      next: "Siguiente ›"
      previous: "‹ Anterior"
      truncate: "..."
```

He intentado traducir los modelos como [aparece en la guía de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), al igual que con infinidades de otras posibles soluciones, pero no funciona.

```
activerecord:
    models:
      customer: Cliente

activerecord:
    models:
      customer:
        one: Cliente
        other: Clientes

 activerecord:
      models:
        admin_user:
          one: "Usuario"
          other: "Usuarios"
```

**Edición:**

Quite la gema *rails-i18n* y logré traducir el mensaje que aparece al intentar eliminar el registro:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      admin_user:
        one: "Usuario"
        other: "Usuarios"
      maintenance:
        one: "Mantenimiento"
        other: "Mantenimientos"
      customer:
        one: "Cliente"
        other: "Clientes"
      equipment:
        one: "Equipo"
        other: "Equipos"
      support:
        one: "Soporte"
        other: "Soportes"
      task:
        one: "Tarea"
        other: "Tareas"
    errors: 
      messages: 
        record_invalid: "La validación falló: %{errors}"
        restrict_dependent_destroy: 
          has_many: "El registro no puede ser eliminado pues existen %{record} dependientes"
          has_one: "El registro no puede ser eliminado pues existe un %{record} dependiente"
```

El problema es que debería traducirse también los nombres en plural, `maintenances` sigue apareciendo en el mensaje de error con el nombre en inglés, aún existiendo la traducción `other: "Mantenimientos"`.

En la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Maintenance.model_name.human => "Mantenimiento"
Maintenance.model_name.human(:count => 2) => "Mantenimientos"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Pero no veo dentro de tus traducciones la que efectivamente te está reclamando que falta:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        admin_user:
          attributes:
            base:
              restrict_dependent_destroy:
                has_many: 'No se puede eliminar...'
```

¿Has probado con eso?

Comment: Si lo había probado, agregué una edición al tema principal, mencionando el suceso actual.